# Flask extensions requiring models fields to have a particular convention

Tags: python, flask

So I'm working on an webapp using Flask. I followed a naming convention in my data models but it seemed that this convention does not properly integrate well with Flask-extensions for specific field naming, quoting for instance, from [Flask-Security extension](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/models.html#models)

> **Models**
>
> Flask-Security assumes you’ll be using libraries such as SQLAlchemy,
>   MongoEngine, Peewee or PonyORM to define a data model that includes a
>   User and Role model. **The fields on your models must follow a
>   particular convention depending on the functionality your app
>   requires**. Aside from this, you’re free to add any additional fields to
>   your model(s) if you want. At the bare minimum your User and Role
>   model should include the following fields:
>
> User
>
> ```
> id
> email
> password
> active
> ```
>
> **...**

Now assume my user model is something like:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    '''This model represents all types of Users registered'''

    __tablename__ = 'users'


    user_id            = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_email         = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    user_password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

If I have to change my model's field to what Flask-extension requires, that requires me to change in a lot of files, which is a tedious task to do.

What I thought of is something like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    '''This model represents all types of Users registered'''

    __tablename__ = 'users'


    user_id            = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id                 = self.user_id #For Flask-Extensions

    user_email         = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    email              = self.user_email #For Flask-Extensions

    user_password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    password           = self.user_password_hash #For Flask-Extensions
```

How bad is this solution and what alternatives I have?

Comment: `Flask extensions` are using other name of `User` fields. You want to tie your fields(from db) with some aliases. Did I understand properly?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar, not only in my DB but in the Python Models as well, without having to rename them through the whole webapp.

Comment: Did you try to use [synonym](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#synonyms)? I think this is what you need.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar, yea, that seems so.

Comment: good luck ; - )

Comment: Thanks, Can you post it as answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [Synonyms](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#synonyms).

> I didn't check but I think this should works.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import synonym


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    user_id            = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id                 = synonym('user_id')

    user_email         = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    email              = synonym('user_email')

    user_password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    password           = synonym('user_password_hash')
```

Answer (score 1):

that's more or less workable and something I've done. I'd recommend implementing it using a property:

```
@property
def id(self):
    return self.user_id
```

If Flask-Security needs the property accessible at the class level as well, you can use SQLAlchemy's [`hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property) instead.

Comment: I just want to know, why is this recommended over the way I've posted on my question?

Comment: Well for one, you can't refer to `self` directly in the body of the class, it's only accessible in the body of the property function because `self` is declared as a parameter. Doing `id = user_id` would be syntactically correct, but I wouldn't recommend it because SQLAlchemy may not handle it the way you expect - for example it may think `id` is supposed to be a separate DB column, or get confused and throw an error. What I've recommended I'm sure will work, and has the added benefit of making the new properties read-only so you can control whether Flask-Security can change your values.